# error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, variables, cs50

I write this code and declare the `c` variable in if chains,
but the compiler gives me an error saying you did not declare this variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int k = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf ("%i\n", k);

    string p = get_string ("Plaintext: \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(p[i]))
        {
            if (islower(p[i]))
            {
                char c = (((p[i] - 97) + k) % 26) + 97;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (isupper(p[i]))
            {
                char c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                char c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
            }

            p[i] = c;
        }
    }
    printf ("%s\n", p);
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
test2.c: In function ‘main’:
test2.c:34:20: error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   34 |             p[i] = c;
      |                    ^
test2.c:34:20: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: All three of those `c`'s are in nested scopes, and are no longer accessible by the time you reach `p[i] = c;`. Since there is only one code path that can possible be taken to reach `p[i] = c;`, move  that line inside the else branch scope directly above.

Comment: Instead of those `char c = ` steps you could do `p[i] = ` directly.

Comment: You should avoid using magic numbers. Especially if you mean letters where the numerical values actually is implementation defined. Instad of `65` use `'A'` etc.

Answer (score 2):

'If' block itself is a scope, and you define a scope and the variables are only accessible inside the scope, not outside, and not at the boundary either.

For sure, the c variable should be declared outside the For loop:

```
char c = ' ';
for ...
```

Comment: yeah, thanks. You know, I thought since one of these if statements will run, so the c variable will be defined. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yeah it's wrong. It's not about the variable is defined or not. It's about scope of a varable. You can read here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/scope-of-variables-in-c-local-and-global-scope-explained/#:~:text=In%20simple%20terms%2C%20scope%20of,about%20local%20scope%20of%20variables

Answer (score 1):

The error would occur at following line:

```
        p[i] = c;
```

It is because `c` is local scope at the following line:

```
        if (islower(p[i]))
        {
            char c = (((p[i] - 97) + k) % 26) + 97;
            return 0;
        }
```

and

```
        {
            char c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
            return 0;
        }
```

and

```
        else{
            char c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
        }
```

Local scope means that it will be released after exit the `}`.

Additionally, after first 2 condition of `if`, `else if`, there is also `return` after define value to `c`. If so, the API will return immediate and `c` is not used at any line because the assignment `p[i] = c;` will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You declare c as a local scope !
So you should declare c before this **if** statements like that:

```
        if (isalpha(p[i]))
        {
        char c = 0;
        if (islower(p[i]))
        {
            c = (((p[i] - 97) + k) % 26) + 97;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (isupper(p[i]))
        {
            c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            c = (((p[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
        }
        p[i] = c;
```